# AWS always request MFA code in the browser with Microsoft Authenticator - Can you get it to prompt on your phone?

Tags: amazon-web-services, multi-factor-authentication

I use Microsoft Authenticator for my MFA needs.  When I log into O365 and need a second authentication factor it will send the request to my device where it prompts me to accept or reject the login there.  Even better, I can accept it on my watch without taking my phone out of my pocket.  I can also key the code from the Authenticator app into the browser where I'm trying to access the O365 service, but the prompt works most of the time.

I recently started working with AWS and using their MFA setup and added it to Microsoft Authenticator.  Whenever I start a new AWS session I'm prompted for my MFA code, which I can retrieve from the Authenticator app, but it doesn't have the oh-so-convenient prompt on my phone and watch that I can just click to say "authorize".  Is there something I can do to make AWS prompt me to approve logins via my phone, or is that some sort of Microsoft-only access that O365 has?  Or can I get that functionality from a different authentication app?